# About multiple objectives in Inception networks

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, inception

Inception networks, in contrast to most of the networks, can have multiple outputs, from which the gradient can propagate in order to update the weights.

[image]

These outputs can have different size and solve different tasks.

> Do I correctly understand, that the main point in doing so, that the
> common for both output heads part of the CNN learns useful information
> from both inputs simultaneously?

To get something sensible, these two tasks most likely need to correlate in a certain way, share a lot of in common. Otherwise, It looks like, the gradient updates from both heads may interfere with each other, and one does not achieve a good solution for either of the tasks.

> The distance from the input to one of the heads can differ a lot from
> the distance to another head. How to choose the learning rates to be
> adjusted, and the proportion of the net loss for each of the
> objectives?